# Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ be a multiplicative set of $R$ then there exists a prime ideal $P$ of $R$ such that $P \cap S= \phi$.

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ be a multiplicative set of $R$ then there exists a prime ideal $P$ of $R$ such that $P \cap S= \phi$

I am reading the proof of this result from [here](https://planetmath.org/multiplicativesetsinringsandprimeideals) but I don't see why do we need to assume $R$ is $\textbf{commutative}$. Can someone please explain me this?

Answer (score 0):

Commutativity is required because that is the context: all the definitions of "prime" and "multiplicative set" are depending on it.

You can drop commutativity, but then you need to be sure your definition of "prime" and "multiplicative set" is going to work in the statement as intended.

Currently the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings) discusses this.  You'd need to use the following definitions:

- a proper ideal $P$ of $R$ is called prime if for any two ideals $A,B$, $AB\subseteq P$ implies $A\subseteq P$ or $B\subseteq P$.
- a nonempty subset $S$ of $R$ is called an m-system if for any $a,b\in S$ there exists an $r\in R$ such that $arb\in S$.

Then, given an m-system $S$, it can be proven that an ideal that is maximal with respect to being disjoint from $S$ is a prime ideal of $R$ (using the noncommutative definition of prime.)